# Network users S-L-O-W on macOS High Sierra

Tags: macos, high-sierra, performance, network-user

I have an old MacBook Pro (Mid-2010 13″, 2.4GHz Core 2 Duo, 8GB 1067MHz DDR3) that I’m trying to set up for my daughter to use for covid-induced home school. I replaced the old HD with an SSD and gave it a brand new install of macOS High Sierra—nothing fancy, nothing imported; just a nice, new, clean install. I created a local admin account and it runs beautifully. But of course, it couldn’t be that simple.

My family uses network accounts from a Mac mini server that doubles as our file and media server. This allows us to log into any computer in the house without worrying about what’s where. The accounts just work, never any problems. But for some reason, when I logged my daughter into this brand new, perfectly clean computer, everything was *s-l-o-w*. Like, crazy slow: click a button and nothing happens for 10-15 minutes slow.

Anyone have any ideas? As I said, the local account works beautifully on the MBP, and the network accounts work beautifully on every other machine in the house. It’s just the confluence of this particular MBP and the network accounts that’s problematic.

Thanks!

Comment: What are the specs of the "old MacBook Pro"?  You say this is an old computer but later say it's "brand new".  Which one is it?  Your title says "Network users" but you don't mention anything about the network, you only indicate the computer was slow.  What, specifically, is slow?  Accessing network shares, internet browsing, non-network tasks?  Can you please [edit] your question to be as specific as possible and include any steps you took to fix the problem yourself.

Comment: Thanks @fsb. I added the specs, but perhaps I need explain a bit: the computer is old; the SSD and the OS are brand new. Does that make more sense? Thanks!

Comment: The edit helped a bit but you didn't address what's slow, the laptop, the network, accessing files on your Mini, etc?  How did this laptop perform prior to the SSD replacement?  Remember, we're not looking over your shoulder so we can't see what you see; we need exact descriptions.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, only the network account is slow, local accounts are fast, right? Does it only happen with the account of your daughter, or with all network accounts? Can you run Activity Monitor (or log in from remote with ssh and run `top -o cpu`) to see whether anything takes a lot of CPU time?